# Regular expressions in django url

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

My URL regular expression is `r'^admin.*/static/admin/(?P<path>.*)$'`, now it can match `admin/static/admin/css/base.css` or `admin/123/static/admin/js/actions.js`, but I want it match url like `admin/blog/post/static/static/admin/js/actions.js` (now it doesn't match that)

How could i do that?

Thanks for everyone's comments.

My problem is I set up static url path in django to store my css/js file,like this `url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,}),` 
settings.STATIC_ROOT is `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'static')`

But when I access admin interface, all css/js files are missing. because admin css file store in `django\contrib\admin\static\admin` and its url in html file is 'static/admin/css/base.css'. there is no this file in my static path I set in settings.

My solution is set another url like `r'^admin.*/static/admin/(?P<path>.*)$'`, and set document root to django admin static file path. but just as i mentioned, when i go admin main page, everything is ok, my when i go deep like "add User" page, css file is still missing.

I also found a solution is change my url regular to `r'.*/static/admin/(?P<path>.*)$'`, that's fine for everything, but is there any better solution?

After I run collectstatic,in my static path, i can found admin folder and its css/js files. then i set my url path to url(r'^admin/static/(?P.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root'‌​:settings.STATIC_ROOT}), ,it works for main admin page, but when i access `http://localhost/admin/sites/site/static/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObje‌​ctLookups.js` it still doesn't work, how could I write my url path?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Why do this, are you string to put static files into your web templates?

Comment: I'm not sure why that wouldn't match, I just escaped the slashes, removed the capture group's name and it works for me on http://www.rubular.com/r/DlxE1mejvL

Comment: The admin resources shouldn't move around.  What's STATIC_URL in your configuration?  Have you run `manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Wait, did that fix the issue?

Comment: @Fredrik Not yet, I run collectstatic, and in my static path, i can found admin folder and its css/js files. then i set my url path to `url(r'^admin/static/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',{'document_root':settings.STATIC_ROOT}),` ,it works for main admin page, but when i access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sites/site/static/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js` it still doesn't work, 
how could I write my url path?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern matches just fine:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r'^admin.*/static/admin/(?P<path>.*)$')
>>> p.match("admin/blog/post/static/static/admin/js/actions.js").groups()
('js/actions.js',)
```

so not clear why it didn't work for you.  Have you double-checked that the problematic URL doesn't match some other, earlier regexp?

EDIT: Based on updates above, it may be that `STATIC_URL` isn't properly set (an empty string, perhaps?).  It should point to where the static files are served from (URL, not directory) and must end with a slash.  See [Settings: STATIC_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#static-url).

(And as a footnote, you should be a bit careful with having your URL regexps do too much; you're not there yet with this one, but Wikipedia's [ReDoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS) article is good to read before you go beyond what you're doing here.)